# confusion_matrix y classification_report para evaluar un modelo en Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, evaluación

Estoy intentando evaluar un modelo que he creado con Spacy para el reconocimiento de enfermedades en unos informes médicos. Estoy intentando evaluar el modelo en el dataset de test. Para eso tengo lo siguiente:

- Un dataframe (df) con 3 columnas: Nombre del archivo del informe **(Archivo)**, códigos de la enfermedad **(CEI10)**  y los *nombres de esas enfermedades **(Antecedente)**, este df fue anotado directamente por personas.
- El dataframe (df2) que obtengo después de todo el proceso que mi modelo me genera con la misma estructura pero con los códigos y enfermedades que ha encontrado.

Sería algo como esto:

df

```
    Archivo                     CEI10   Antecedente
0   S0004-06142005000500011-1   C67.9   carcinoma urotelial superficial de vejiga
1   S0004-06142005000500011-1   E11.9   Diabetes Mellitus tipo II
2   S0004-06142005000500011-1   F10.20  enolismo activo
3   S0004-06142005000500011-1   F17.210 cigarrillos
4   S0004-06142006000100010-1   E11.9   diabetes
5   S0004-06142006000100010-1   I10 hipertensa
6   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma de células renales claras
7   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma renal
8   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma renal
9   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C79.31  cerebral metástasis
10  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C79.82  metástasis en pene
11  S0004-06142006000500012-1   I82.3   trombosis vena renal derecha
12  S0004-06142006000500012-1   I82.90  trombo
13  S0004-06142006000700011-1   C20 adenocarcinoma rectal
14  S0004-06142006000700011-1   C26.0   adenocarcinoma intestinal
15  S0004-06142006000700011-1   C79.2   metástasis subcutáneas
16  S0004-06142006000700012-1   C64.9   nefroma
17  S0004-06142006000700012-1   C64.9   nefroma
18  S0004-06142006000700012-1   D72.1   eosinofilia
19  S0004-06142006000700012-1   D72.1   eosinofilia
```

df2

```
    Archivo                     CEI10   Antecedente
0   S0004-06142005000500011-1   C07 carcinoma
1   S0004-06142005000500011-1   E11.9   Diabetes Mellitus tipo II
2   S0004-06142005000500011-1   F10.20  enolismo
3   S0004-06142005000500011-1   F17.210 fumador
4   S0004-06142005000500011-1   NaN enfermedad de Dupuytren
5   S0004-06142005000500011-1   NaN pseudodiverticulosis ureteral
6   S0004-06142005000900014-1   NaN leiomioma vesical
7   S0004-06142006000100010-1   I10 hipertensa
8   S0004-06142006000100010-1   NaN mielolipoma de la glándula adrenal
9   S0004-06142006000500012-1   C07 carcinoma
10  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma de células renales
11  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma renal
12  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C64.9   carcinoma renal
13  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
14  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
15  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
16  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
17  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
18  S0004-06142006000500012-1   C78.1   metástasis
19  S0004-06142006000500012-1   I82.90  trombosis
```

Ahora lo que necesito saber es cuántos de los códigos que están en cada archivo de df están en df2 para ver cuanto de bueno o malo es mi modelo.
Para obtener precision, recall y f1-score había pensado en algo como

```
confusion_matrix(df['CEI10'], df2['CEI10'])
```

y

```
print(classification_report(df['CEI10'], df2['CEI10']))
```

pero me da error al no tener el mismo número de filas los dos df. En df2 donde están los que ha encontrados mi modelo hay algunas entradas que no tienen código asociado y que se podrían descartar con  `df2 = df2.dropna()` pero el número de líneas de mi df2 nunca va a coincidir con el df inicial.

¿como puedo hacer para evaluar mi modelo utilizando estos dos dataframes?

Gracias.

Comment: Podrias tomar una muestra, en caso que el df2 siempre tenga menos que el de inicial puedes escoger ese número de datos

Comment: En df son los casos anotados por personas, tiene 610 y df2 los encontrados por el modelo 651 (ha encontrado mas enfermedades que las anotadas). El tema es saber lo siguiente: df tiene nombres de archivos con sus correspondientes códigos de enfermedad, lo que necesito saber es el porcentaje de esos códigos que ha encontrado el modelo. Por ejemplo en df el archivo S0004-06142005000500011-1 contiene C67.9, E11.9, F10.20 y F17.210. En df2 en el mismo archivo el modelo ha encontrado C07, E11.9, F10.20 y F17.210. Necesito saber esto mismo para todos nombre de archivo que contiene df.